# Issue after software update: "Failed to set SSL cipher list error:1410D0B9:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list: no cipher match"

Tags: perl, openssl, openldap, starttls

Several years ago I wrote a Perl CGI script that connects to an openLDAP server and starts TLS when available.

The script was running successfully with openLDAP-2.4.41 of SLES12 SP5 without a problem, but after updating some packages, the script cannot start TLS using `$ldap->start_tls` any more.

The error message is:

> "Failed to set SSL cipher list error:1410D0B9:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list: no cipher match"

The updates installed were (AFAIK) `openldap2-2.4.41-22.5.1` together with `libopenssl1_1-1.1.1d-2.54.1`. Specifically there was no update for the Perl LDAP modules.

My code does not specify a ciphers list, but is specifies the CA path and used `require` for certificate verification.

The part of the code that outputs the error message is:

```perl
$msg = $ldap->start_tls(%options);
if ($msg->code()) {
    perr($q 'start_TLS() failed: ', $msg->error);
}
```

A truly odd thing is that a simple test case started on a different server (that should have the same software) succeeds with cipher `AES256-GCM-SHA384`.
Even when I run that script on the same server, it succeeds with the same cipher.
The code used in the test case basically is:

```perl
my $m = $l->start_tls(verify => 'verify');
$m->code() || print $l->cipher(), "\n";
```

While looking closer, I noticed that my CA path is `/etc/ssl/certs` which is a symbolic link to `/var/lib/ca-certificates/pem` updated about the same time as the other RPM packages.
Even when changing the CA path in the CGI to `/var/lib/ca-certificates/pem` I get the same error.

The web server being used was updated with the other packages, too; it it `apache2-2.4.51-35.7.1`.
The Perl code runs with `PerlResponseHandler ModPerl::Registry`, and the apache RPM changelog says it was "build against openssl 1.1".

What might be wrong or causing this, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my CGI script magically worked again after having installed current SLES 12 SP5 updates, I must assume that there was a bad update causing the failure.

Suspecting that the packages causing that might have been apache2, perl, or openssl, I try to find the bad versions:

apache2-2.4.51-35.7.1
libopenssl1_1-1.1.1d-2.54.1
were probably the bad versions, while
libopenssl0_9_8-0.9.8j-106.33.1
apache2-2.4.51-35.13.1
openssl1_0_0-1.0.2p-3.48.1
fixed the problem again.